# Simply trying to initialize a CLLocationCoordinate2D, getting EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Tags: swift, core-location, swift-playground

Why would this cause an error in a Swift Playground?

```
import Cocoa
import CoreLocation
let loc = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 43.0777, longitude: -79.0754)
```

error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).

Comment: Seems to be a playground bug. Importing MapKit instead of (or in addition to) CoreLocation seems to make it work for some reason, though.

Comment: Yes, MapKit works, thank you